# How to save changes of Pandas data frame into a new file using pd.to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, save

Trying to use a small example to explain my case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]],columns=['A', 'B'])
d1 = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>3}'.format(x))
df['B'] = d1
df.head()
df.to_csv()
```

I want to save changed df into a new csv file, which should be like:

```
Out[28]: A    B
      0  1  001
      1  1  002
      2  1  003
      3  1  004
```

But after saved it used df.to_csv(), the new data file has no changes:

```
Out[32]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
```

Anyone could happy to tell how to fix it? many thanks!

Comment: how are you viewing the file?

Comment: yes, I can viewed the new file which is same as the original one...

Comment: I didn't ask if you could view the file. I asked how you were viewing the file.

Comment: read this while you're at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. So again, I'll ask: *how* are you viewing the CSV after you've saved it? In a text editor? In Excel?

Comment: I viewed it in Python, use of.read_csv. my actual file contains 2 more million rows...

Comment: Using text editor viewed the saved file, it works. Why use python to view it does not work??

Comment: so your question is actually: "how to do I preserve leading zeros when I read in a CSV file with pandas?"

Comment: looks like searching "pandas leading zeros" on this site turns up a lot of useful answers.